# Real life example of S ≺ R if and only if Inv(S) ≺ R, here, S and R are roles, relations, or properties

Tags: relations, order-theory

The first requirement of a *generalized role hierarchy* to be regular is as follows:

$S \prec R$ if and only if $S^{-} \prec R$.

The above is used in the context of $\mathcal{SROIQ}$ RBoxes.

*(For reference, please see page 168 of [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/142009050X) or page 83 of [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3642230318).)*

Here, a role (or a relation) can be explained with an example.

The expression

```
hasAffiliation(rudiStuder, aifb)
```

describes that `rudiStuder` is affiliated with `aifb`. Here, `hasAffiliation`
is a  role. A role is sometimes referred to as a relation or property in some literature.

If we name the inverse of role `hasAffiliation` as `employs`, we can express the same fact using the inverse role as,

```
employs(aifb, rudiStuder)
```

I was wondering whether somebody can put forth a real-life example where
both a role (relation) $S$ and its inverse $S^{-}$ maintain strict partial order with
another role (relation) $R$.

Comment: You should define your terms if you don't want to limit the people who can answer your question to the people who own one of these two textbooks.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Tried to add a few lines. Hope this suffices. And thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: For example $S(x,y)=$ 'x is a parent of y' and $R(x,y)=$ 'x,y are relatives to each other' (or, 'belong to the same species')...

Comment: @Berci Yes, indeed. Things sound so simple once the proper answers are found. Want to convert your comment to a full answer which I can accept?